# problem remapping a key while using vim's CommandT plugin

Tags: vim

I'm using the [Command T plugin](https://wincent.com/products/command-t) for vim and trying to remap a key. The default for starting CommandT is `<leader> t` but I am **not** trying to change this. In order to refresh the file list for CommandT there's a :CommandTFlush command. I am trying to map this to `<leader> f` So I put this in my .vimrc file but it's not working

```
map <leader>f :CommandTFlush<CR>
```

Once I add the line above to my .vimrc file hitting `<leader> t` doesn't work either, nothing happens. Any idea what is going on or at least some help on how I can try and figure out what the problem is? I have no idea where to even start.

EDIT: Turns out there was a bug in CommandT causing this behavior. The plugin author has applied a fix for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this, but only by adding it to the vimrc file - adding it directly into the vim session worked fine. So it's an ordering problem.

What I did to fix it: add an explicit mapping for `:CommandT` to `<leader>t` in the .vimrc file right around where you're adding the `<leader>f` mapping - before vs. after doesn't matter between those two.

Comment: thanks! so strange that it's so easy to repro yet i can't find info about it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can try typing `:map` to see a list of all your mappings, maybe something is already mapped to f? Maybe that gets precedence over what you set in your .vimrc, I'm not sure what gets loaded first, your .vimrc or plugin settings.

If you set things in your vim session that would get precedence over what has been set before I think.

Also try `map <leader>f` to see the binding for leader f :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by mapping CommandT to ct as i did it in my .vimrc:

```
nmap <leader>ct :CommandT<CR>
```

You can replace the mapping to any other letter(s).